# SQL Server Query - Weird Behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider below SQL.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT bvc_Order.ID,
            bvc_OrderItem.ProductID,
            bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID
FROM dbo.bvc_OrderItem WITH (nolock)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.bvc_Order WITH (nolock)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.bvc_User WITH (nolock) ON dbo.bvc_Order.UserID = dbo.bvc_User.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Amazon_Merchants WITH (nolock) ON dbo.bvc_Order.CompanyID = dbo.Amazon_Merchants.ID ON dbo.bvc_OrderItem.OrderID = dbo.bvc_Order.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem WITH (nolock) ON dbo.bvc_OrderItem.ID = dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.OrderItemID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.bvc_Product WITH (nolock) ON dbo.bvc_OrderItem.ProductID = dbo.bvc_Product.ID
WHERE 1=1
AND (bvc_Order.StatusCode <> 1
   AND bvc_Order.StatusCode <> 999)
AND ( bvc_OrderItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00')
   OR bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00'))
AND bvc_Order.OrderSource = 56;
```

The query when I execute against my database, it returns 85 rows. Well, that is not correct. 
If I just remove the part "AND bvc_Order.OrderSource = 56" it returns back 5 rows which is really correct.
Strange.....
Another thing, if I remove the part

```
OR bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00')
```

it will also return the 5 rows as expected even with bvc_Order.OrderSource filter.
I am not sure why it is adding more rows while I am trying to reduce rows by using filters.

the table bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem doesn't contain any rows for the result order ids or OrderItemIDs

**[edit]**

Thanks guys, I tried to remove the LEFT/RIGHT Join Mix but Query manager doesn't allows only LEFT, it does add at least one RIGHT join. I updated the SQL to remove extra tables and now we have only three. But same result

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.bvc_Order.ID, dbo.bvc_OrderItem.ProductID, dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID AS Expr1
FROM         dbo.bvc_OrderItem 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem ON dbo.bvc_OrderItem.ID = dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.OrderItemId 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.bvc_Order ON dbo.bvc_OrderItem.OrderID = dbo.bvc_Order.ID

WHERE 1=1
AND (bvc_Order.StatusCode <> 1 AND bvc_Order.StatusCode <> 999)
AND ( 
    bvc_OrderItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00')
   OR bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00')
  )
AND bvc_Order.OrderSource = 56;
```

[edit]So far, there is no solution for this. I previously pasted a link in my comment with example data outout for both valid/invalid results with queries. here it is again.
http://sameers.me/SQLIssue.xlsx

One thing to remember here is that ALL left join is not possible. Let me explain further
bvc_Order contains main order record
bvc_ORderItem contains Order Items/Products
bvc_ORderItem_BundleItem contains child products of the product which are available in bvC_OrderItem table.

Now NOT Every product has child products, so bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem may not have any record (and in current scenario, there is really no valid row for the orders in bvC_OrderItem_BundleItem). 
In short, in current scenario, there is NO matching row available in bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem table. If I remove that join for now, it is all okay, but in real world, I can't remove that BundleItem table join ofcourse.

thank you

Comment: Mixing left and right outer joins in a query is just confusing.  You should start by rewriting the `from` clause to only use one type (and I strongly recommend `left outer join`).

Comment: Also remember to put the left join's right side table conditions in the ON clause.

Comment: Get rid of that (nolock) that's bad practice now (and begin in the past 10 years). Write and format it and put an example with data in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so we can find what's happening here. From my experience weird behaviour comes from bad writen queries the engines merely try to do what you instructed it to do.

Comment: Please, use aliases!

Comment: And why you join this tables: `dbo.bvc_User`, `dbo.Amazon_Merchants`, `dbo.bvc_Product` and don't use them?

Comment: Using `WITH (NOLOCK)` may provide a negligible performance boost, but your query results will be unreliable.

Comment: Thank you guys, I tried to remove the LEFT/RIGHT and only use LEFT but SQL query manager doesn't seems to be working that way. It is adding RIGHT JOIN to at least one table. A more simplified query is like this

Comment: @gofr1 It was actually part of a big query and I removed most of the part from it. Now I simplified the query with only related tables, see my edited post above.

Comment: Even removing with nolock doesnt help. I wish I could share the data somehow, but the actual db is very big and I am not sure how to simulate that with fiddle

Comment: Try and replicate in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I don't get how you can't change your own code (removing right joins)? Aren't you coding this SQL query?

Comment: Updated Query with ALL LEFT JOINS still same SELECT DISTINCT dbo.bvc_Order.ID, dbo.bvc_OrderItem.ProductID, dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID AS Expr1
FROM         dbo.bvc_Order  
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.bvc_OrderItem ON dbo.bvc_Order.ID = dbo.bvc_OrderItem.OrderID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem ON dbo.bvc_OrderItem.ID = dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.OrderItemId 


WHERE 1=1
AND (bvc_Order.StatusCode <> 1 AND bvc_Order.StatusCode <> 999)
AND ( 
    bvc_OrderItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00')
   OR bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00')
  )
AND bvc_Order.OrderSource = 56;

Comment: Is `dbo.bvc_OrderItem` and `dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem` relate only on `dbo.bvc_OrderItem.ID = dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.OrderItemId` and there is no relation on `ProductID` field in both tables?

Comment: bvc_OrderItem contains ProductID, and bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem also contains ProductID, however, the ProductID in bvc_OrderITem can never be in bvC_OrderItem_BundleItem table. So we can't create a join for ProductID field in both tables.

Comment: "Query manager doesn't allows only LEFT"?   What tool is forcing you to include a RIGHT?   Your first join has no ON.

Comment: Please run your "Updated Query with ALL LEFT JOINS" in the comment and post the 5 correct result records and 85 incorrect result records into your question.  What is it about the other 80 records that is incorrect?

Comment: I think that your solution may lie in the relationship between the bvc_OrderItem and bvc.OrderItem_BundleItem tables to the bvc_Order table. You are joining the bvc_Order table to bvc_OrderItem, but not to bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem. Could you explain the relationship between these tables?

Comment: Hi,  Here is the results from two queries. Main thing we need to focus on is, WHY when add a filter, it includes extra results. I included the SQL for ALL LEFT JOINS, with same issue [See Excel With results and Queries](http://sameers.me/SQLIssue.xlsx)

Comment: Did you find the reason for the extra rows?

Comment: Hi John, No, I didn't found a solution. Peoples are trying to use ALL INNER Join, but I can't since OrderID could be available in bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem or NOT. but there is always a row in bvc_OrderItem.

Comment: As I said in my answer below, I believe that your problem is not caused by the join types, inner or outer. Did my answer  give you any ideas about other kinds of problems to investigate? And which tool do you use to test these queries and get the result sets that you put into the excel files.

Answer (score 10):

When you say

```
WHERE bvc_Order.OrderSource = 56
```

that evaluates to false when `bvc_Order.OrderSource` is `NULL`. If the `LEFT/RIGHT` join failed then it will be `NULL`. This effectively turns the `LEFT/RIGHT` join into an inner join.

You probably should write the predicate into the `ON` clause. An alternative approach, which might not deliver the same results, is:

```
WHERE (bvc_Order.OrderSource IS NULL OR bvc_Order.OrderSource = 56)
```

The other predicates have the same problem:

> Another thing, if I remove the part `OR bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00')` it will also return the 5 rows as expected

When the join fails `bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID` is `NULL`.

I also would recommend writing queries manually. If I understand you right this query comes from a designer. It's structure is quite confusing. I'm pulling up the most important comment:

> Mixing left and right outer joins in a query is just confusing. You should start by rewriting the from clause to only use one type (and I strongly recommend left outer join). – Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 2):

> When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however
>   improbable, must be the truth?  *S.H.*

It is impossible that an extra AND condition appended to a WHERE clause can ever result in extra rows.  That would imply a database engine defect, which I hope I can assume is "impossible".  (If not, then I guess it's back to square one).

That fact makes it easier to concentrate on possible reasons:

1. When you comment out

   ```
   AND bvc_Order.OrderSource = 56;
   ```

   then you also comment out the semicolon terminator.  Is it possible
   that there is text following this query that is affecting it?  Try
   putting a semicolon at the end of the previous line to make sure.
2. Depending on the tool you are using to run queries, sometimes when a
   query fails to execute, the tool mistakenly shows an old result set.
   Make sure your query is executing correctly by adding a dummy column
   to the SELECT statement to absolutely prove you are seeing live
   results.  Which tool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

when you use LEFT outer join it will give all the rows from left table (dbo.bvc_OrderItem) once the your and, or conditions satisfies, 
the same thing happens with Right outer join too,

Those conditions (Left join, right join ) may not restrict the rows since rows from one table can be all, another table with some rows only.

check with your join condition

Then check you condition :
(bvc_Order.StatusCode <> 1 AND bvc_Order.StatusCode <> 999)
if any rows satisfying this condition
next check with another condition 
[bvc_OrderItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00')
   OR bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00')]

Then bvc_Order.OrderSource = 56

compare the result of three queries and check the data in with the conditions and then write your complete query, so that you will understand where the mistake you have done.

Answer (score 1):

bLike @usr writ, the reason of this unexpected (for you) result is, you build query with outer joins, and filter rows after join. If you need filter rows of outer joined tables, you should do this before join.
but probably you try build this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.ID, oi.ProductID, bi.ProductID AS Expr1
FROM dbo.bvc_Order as o       
LEFT JOIN dbo.bvc_OrderItem as oi on oi.OrderID = o.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem as bi ON oi.ID = bi.OrderItemId 
WHERE 1=1
AND o.OrderSource = 56;
AND o.StatusCode not in (1, 999)
AND '28046_00' in (oi.ProductID, isnull(bi.ProductID,'_') )
```

Is this query give results what you need?
if not, try change last condition, for example:

```
and (bi.ProductID = '28046_00' or bi.ProductID is null and oi.ProductID = '28046_00')
```

you can also put additional condition in to join conditions, for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.ID, oi.ProductID, bi.ProductID AS Expr1
FROM dbo.bvc_Order as o       
LEFT JOIN dbo.bvc_OrderItem as oi on oi.OrderID = o.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem as bi ON oi.ID = bi.OrderItemId
and bi.ProductID in ('28046_00') --this join BundleItem only if ...
WHERE 1=1
AND o.OrderSource = 56;
AND o.StatusCode not in (1, 999)
AND (oi.ProductID in ('28046_00') or bi.ProductID is not null)
```

ah, and if you always need join bvc_Order with bvc_OrderItem then use inner join

Comment: Hi, this all LEFT join is NOT possible, since as I explained earlier, I have to check and select rows if that exists in bvc_OrderItem OR in bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem. If any of these two tables contains the PRoductID, I need to select rows from bvc_Order AND bvc_OrderItem. Remember, if there is a row with OrderID in bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem, there is always a row in bvc_OrderItem with same OrderID. But with different ProductID in both bvc_ORderItem and bvc_ORderItem_BundleItem

Comment: did you test my query? is there any error or bad result? this isn't your left joins...  this join is like: bvc_Order < bvc_OrderItem <  bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem  where < is like 'one to many' ... If bvc_OrderItem.OrderID always exists in bvc_Order.id then you need only inner join of this tables

Answer (score 1):

Few points to remember
1.And is applied during Virtual join phases
2.Where clause is applied after the final result
3.Left join followed by right join is effectively an inner join in some cases

Lets break your query step by step..

```
dbo.bvc_OrderItem  a1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem b1
```

Above output will be a single virtual table (logically) which contains all rows from b1 with matching rows from a1

now below predicates from your and clause will be applied

```
bvc_OrderItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00')
   OR bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00')
```

which effectively eliminates all rows from bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem even if they have matches and gives result some thing like below if bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00') is true

```
bvc_OrderItem   bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem

28046             28046
null              1
null              2
null              3
```

if this condition(bvc_OrderItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00')) is true,then you are asking sql to ignore all rows in bvc_OrderItem ,which effectively means the same result set as above

```
bvc_OrderItem   bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem  other columns

28046             28046
null              1
null              2
null              3
```

next you are doing right outer join with dbo.bvc_Order which may qualifies for the join  point I mentioned above

Assume ,you got below result set as output which preserves all of bvc_order table(rough output only for understanding due to lack of actual data)

```
bvc_OrderItem   bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem  statuscode  ordersource
28046             28046                    999         56
null              1                        1           57
null              2                       100          58
null              3                        11          59
```

Next below AND predicates will be applied

status code <>1 and statuscode<> 999

which means ignore rows which match  with bvc_order and has status  of 1 ,999 even if they found matching rows

Next you are asking  bvc_Order.OrderSource = 56; which means I don't care about other rows,preserve matching rows only for 56 and keep the rest as null

Hope this clarifies on what is happening step by step.A more better way can be provide some test data and show the expected output.

you also can control physical order of joins,you can try below to see if this is what you are trying to do..

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.bvc_Order.ID, dbo.bvc_OrderItem.ProductID, dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID AS Expr1
 dbo.bvc_OrderItem 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
dbo.bvc_Order 
ON dbo.bvc_OrderItem.OrderID = dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.OrderItemId
)c
on 
dbo.bvc_OrderItem.ID = c.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.OrderItemId 

WHERE 1=1
AND (bvc_Order.StatusCode <> 1 AND bvc_Order.StatusCode <> 999)
AND ( 
    bvc_OrderItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00')
   OR bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00')
  )
AND bvc_Order.OrderSource = 56;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the Query Designer.  I would avoid using this as this can make your queries extremely confusing.  Your queries will be much more concise if you are designing them by hand.  If you don't completely understand how inner/outer joins work, a great textbook that I used to teach myself SQL is Murach's SQL Server for Developers.

https://www.murach.com/shop/murach-s-sql-server-2012-for-developers-detail

Now, onto the answer.

I've been thinking about how to resolve your problem, and if you are trying to reduce the result set to 5 rows, why are you using multiple outer joins in the first place?  I would consider switching the joins to inner joins instead of outer joins if you are looking for a very specific result set.  I can't really provide you with a really comprehensive answer without looking at exactly what results you are trying to achieve, but here's a general idea based on what you've provided to all of us:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.bvc_Order.ID, dbo.bvc_OrderItem.ProductID, dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID AS 'bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem_ProductID'
FROM         dbo.bvc_OrderItem 
INNER JOIN dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem ON dbo.bvc_OrderItem.ID = dbo.bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.OrderItemId 
INNER JOIN dbo.bvc_Order ON dbo.bvc_OrderItem.OrderID = dbo.bvc_Order.ID
```

Start here and then based upon what you are searching for, add where clauses to filter criteria.

Also, your where clause must be rewritten if you use an inner join instead of an outer join:

```
WHERE 1=1 --not really sure why this is here.  This will always be true.  Omit this statement to avoid a bad result set.
AND (bvc_Order.StatusCode <> 1 AND bvc_Order.StatusCode <> 999) --this is saying, if the StatusCode is not equal to 1 and not equal to 999, don't include it.  
--Revised: Look for Status codes with 1 or 999
--bvc_Order.StatusCode = 1 OR bvc_Order.StatusCode = 999
    AND (bvc_OrderItem.ProductID IN ('28046_00') --I would eliminate this unless you are looking to see if this exists in Product ID.  You could also accomplish this if you are trying to see if this value is in both tables, change this to:
bvc_OrderItem.ProductID  = '28046_00' AND bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem.ProductID = '28046_00')
--if you are trying to see if the order source is 56, use this.
    AND bvc_Order.OrderSource = 56;
```

If you are trying to find out rows that are not included in this result set, then I would use OUTER JOIN as necessary (LEFT preferred).  Without more information about what you're looking for in your database, that's the best all of us can do.

Comment: Not related to this answer but I can't comment on your original answer since you deleted it. I appreciated the book recommendation. Also it's so stupid that this site bans book recommendations even when explicitly asked for. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that - I'm still pretty new to SO and I got a request to remove my answer about OAuth 2.0.  Glad I could help (albeit a little)!

Comment: Hi, this all LEFT join is NOT possible, since as I explained earlier, I have to check and select rows if that exists in bvc_OrderItem OR in bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem. If any of these two tables contains the PRoductID, I need to select rows from bvc_Order AND bvc_OrderItem. Remember, if there is a row with OrderID in bvc_OrderItem_BundleItem, there is always a row in bvc_OrderItem with same OrderID. But with different ProductID in both bvc_ORderItem and bvc_ORderItem_BundleItem.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on my answer.  I don't have enough rep to ask questions in the comments yet, so this helps me respond.  If you are looking for something that exists in two tables, then you are definitely looking at an inner join - not an outer join.  I can help you with this some more if you invite me to chat with you.  I can try helping you with your query there.